# Show icon over images on specific category listing only

Tags: magento-1.9, product-list, if

I'd like to show an icon only in my 'shoes' category listing page (ID: 3).

I've put in place the PHTML which will create the icon in the `list.phtml` file. But currently it appears in all categories, I want it to appear in just the category 'shoes' which has the ID: 3.

Here's my current code in catalog/product/list.phtml

```
<div style="position:absolute;top:-10px;right:-15px;">
<img src="mysite.com/myshoesimage.png" width="100" alt="My Shoes Cat Specific Icon" />
</div>
```

Can anyone please suggest an edit to make this show only in the specific category?

Comment: Have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
<?php if(Mage::registry('current_category')->getId()==3){ ?>
<div style="position:absolute;top:-10px;right:-15px;">
<img src="mysite.com/myshoesimage.png" width="100" alt="My Shoes Cat Specific Icon" />
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can try:**

```
$catId = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();

if($catId==3):?>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:-10px;right:-15px;">
        <img src="mysite.com/myshoesimage.png" width="100" alt="My Shoes Cat Specific Icon" />
    </div>
<?php endif;?>
```